# Mysql request on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One stores information about a product, and the other has the stores that sell this product. They look like this :
table one

```
category id_product  price  desc
100      p1          10     "prodA"
100      p2          12     "prodB"
100      p3          5      "prodC"
...
```

table two:

```
id_product store
p1         s1    
p1         s3   
p1         s4   
p1         s6       
p1         s14   
p2         s1   
p2         s2       
p3         s1   
p3         s13  
p3         s21
```

What I am trying to figure out is a request that, given a product id from table one, will generate a row for each store of table two that has this product. It should look like (for id_product=p1)

```
store category id_product  price  desc
s1    100      p1          10     "prodA"
s3    100      p1          10     "prodA"
s4    100      p1          10     "prodA"
s6    100      p1          10     "prodA"
s14   100      p1          10     "prodA"
```

The first part is obviously a select... but I'm stuck after that.  Ideally, I would like to use "INTO OUTFILE etc..." and export my data right from mysql. Is there a command that would do what I need, or should I just use two queries and arrange the results/export programatically (it's part of a Node.js app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table2.store, table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
      ON table2.id_product=table1.id_product
WHERE table1.id_product='p1'
INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96ecf/2/0